# Qt: Where to place a connect statement?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget (mainWidget) and another widget (childWidget), that's a child of it.

I want to:

```
connect(childWidget, SIGNAL(somethingHappened(...)), mainWidget, SLOT(handleIt(...));
```

My question is: does one place the connect statement in mainWidget or childWidget?

- If I create the childWidget in the mainWidget's constructor and place
  the connect statement on the next line, it works. But, let's say the 
  childWidget, upon being created, does something and then signals to
  the mainWidget success. You could have a situation where the connect 
  statement only comes after a function (of childWidget) that emits the
  signal.
- If I place the connect statements in the childWidget's constructor,
  the problem is that it doesn't know anything about the parent's
  slots. If I make childWidget inherit mainWidget, it does know about
  the slots - but this feels like a bad solution to me. Couldn't get it
  to work anyway. There is probably a proper way to do this - I'm still
  looking.

I'm quite new to Qt programming.
In advance: thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should design your code well to avoid creeping of mysterious bugs. It would be a better idea to write the connect in the main widget and ideally there should not be an emit in the constructor of the child widget. Possibly you could move out the emit code to another block and do the call after construction is complete. Sub-classing 'childwidget' from 'mainWidget' only to get access to its slot looks like an inflexible design. Design should be such that if any class knows the signal your class emits, the other class should be able to flexibly connect to it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, mots_g. I was thinking that a function might be called from the constructor to create a database connection or to do something else and emit to the mainWidget if that was successful. It would still be before the construction was complete, though.

Comment: When you emit, the signal is only scheduled for dispatch. No slot is called until the event loop continues. So unless you try to call `QApplication::processEvents()` in the constructor (very bad idea), you can safely emit signals from a constructor.

Comment: Cool, I thought it also worked like a direct function call if the signal and slot were in the same slot and connection type was 'DirectConnection'. Also, I wasn't aware that the event loop was blocked in a constructor call..thx

Comment: Thanks again, Nikos. So, one can emit signals from a constructor and they will be dispatched after the construction is done - could be very useful (I'll definitely stay away from QApplication::processEvents(), at least until I have a far better understanding of Qt programming).

Comment: Turns out my answer was wrong. Connections are synchronous by default when they happens inside the same thread, so the event loop doesn't need to be running for a slot to be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

I always do the connect calls after the construction of the object inside the class that created the child. The reason is simple: The object creating the child knows what signal/slot the child has and which it needs for its purpose, but the child can't and more importunity shouldn't know. If the child has more expectations about its parent than necessary you will limit the reusability of your code.

You are right that signals in constructors won't be heard by anyone. Just don't use signals in constructors the same way one shouldn't use virtual functions in constructors. If you have to emit signals upon initialization write a separated `ini` function and call it after `connect`.

You could also use `qobject_cast` to determine the type of the parent at run time, but that is just bad design.

Comment: Thank you JustMaximumPower, what you say about the child having more expectations about its parent than necessary, actually makes perfect sense to me now: if I avoid such things, my 'childWidgets' could be utilized by more 'parentWidgets', than otherwise.